# How to redefine a Vee Validate error message for one Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a global validation rule, for example:

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: 'Please fill the field'
});
```

This rule is using for all Vue components across the project. But for one exact component I need to redefine the message `Please fill the field` to another one. Is it possible to change the message just for one Vue component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specifiy specific messages for each `ValidationProvider` component using the `custom-messages` prop

```html
<ValidationProvider rules="required" :custom-messages="{ required: 'required message' }">
  <!-- ... -->
</ValidationProvider>
```

You can extract it on a data prop and use it for the providers in your component:

```html
<template>
  <ValidationProvider rules="required" :custom-messages="customMessages">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ValidationProvider>

  <ValidationProvider rules="required" :custom-messages="customMessages">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 // ....
 data: () => ({
    customMessages: {
      required: 'custom message'
    }
  }),
  // ...
};
</script>
```

Comment: your solution is working well with required but not working in my case
would you please help me

<ValidationProvider name="Charges" :vid="`Unauthorised Overrun Charges`"
                                                rules="required|decimal_validator_common:10,2,nodecimal" v-slot="{ errors }" :custom-messages="{ decimal_validator_common: 'sachin message', required:'dsklfjs' }">